# $q is not defined in function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Created a factory 'resInterceptor' and in that i am using functions(requestInterceptor,responseInterceptor) that is defined outside of factory. And it is giving error '$q is not defined' inside the function. But i want to do like this way only. Please suggest how to access $q inside requestInterceptor and responseInterceptor.

```
angular.module('resModule', ['ngResource', 'ngCookies'])
 .factory('resInterceptor', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$location', resInterceptor]);

 function resInterceptor($rootScope, $q, $location) {
    return {
        request: requestInterceptor,
        response: responseInterceptor,
    };
}

function requestInterceptor(config) {
   return config || $q.when(config); //$q is not defined
}

function responseInterceptor(response) {
   return response || $q.when(response);
}
```

Comment: `requestInterceptor` is defined in a different scope.  This will obviously not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for this to work, you need to pass `$q` along explicitly and make `requestInterceptor` return your actual callback function:

```
function resInterceptor($rootScope, $q, $location) {
  return {
    request: requestInterceptor($q),
    ..
  };
}

function requestInterceptor($q) {
  return function (config) {
    return config || $q.when(config);
  };
}
```

Of course, this would be less complicated if you simply inlined the functions into the same scope where `$q` is defined in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

```
angular.module('resModule', ['ngResource', 'ngCookies'])
 .factory('resInterceptor', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$location', resInterceptor]);

 function resInterceptor($rootScope, $q, $location) {
    return {
        request: requestInterceptor,
        response: responseInterceptor,
    };

    function requestInterceptor(config) {
       return config || $q.when(config); //$q is defined :)
    }

    function responseInterceptor(response) {
       return response || $q.when(response);
    }
}
```